# How to send data from view to controller with drop down list asp.net core 5 MVC

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

So I'm doing a project in asp.net core and I've got multiple drop down lists which should send data to the controller once I click the submit button. The problem is that i have never been able to send any data to the controller.

Here's the concerned part of the view (there's only one drop down list now but I'll add more):

```
@using DemoProjectCar.Models
@model JoinModels

<form asp-action="searchCar">
    <label for="carType">car Type:</label>
    <select name="carType" id="carType">
        <option value="Aucun" name="data">Aucun</option>
        @foreach (var car in Model.cars)
        {
            <option name="data">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.carType)</option>
        }
    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="SearchButton" type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-dark" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the controller:

```
public IActionResult searchCar(String data)
    {
        //Gets a list of both models in the view
        JoinModels join = getJoinModel();
        
        //Whatever i wanna do with the data
        
        return View("Index", join);
    }
```

Here's both the Join Model and the carModel

```
namespace DemoProjectCar.Models
{
public class JoinModels
{
    public List<_user> user { get; set; }
    public List<_cars> cars { get; set; }
}
}

namespace DemoProjectCar.Models
{
public class _cars
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String carType{ get; set; }

    public cars()
    {

    }
}
}
```

I know something like that would usually work (i think):

```
<select asp-for="id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.message,"id","carType"))">
```

but because I've got a join model it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your HTML:

```
<select asp-for="data" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.cars, "id", "carType"))"></select>
```

And in your ViewModel(JoinModels), you need to create an attribute to send to your Post method:

```
public class JoinModels
{
    // New attribute to receive in your post data
    public string data { get; set; }

    public List<_user> user { get; set; }
    public List<_cars> cars { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your post method `searchCar(String data)`, you will receive the selected Id.

Here's a link to help you more: [Examples about how to create an dropdopwn](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists)